# SwiftUI: Key:Value pair not getting added to dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm working with a dictionary with SwiftUI and I'm simply trying to add a pair to a dictionary. The dictionary is defined as follows:

`@State var dict: [String : Int] = [String : Int]()`

Then, in my `init()` method, I call a function that runs the following code:

```
if dict["test"] == nil {
    dict["test"] = 1
    print(dict["test"])
}
```

However, all the print line only outputs `nil`, does anyone know why?

Comment: Why not `@State var dict: [String : Int] = ["test": 1]`?

Comment: The values don't seem to be the problem, as the same issue occurs with that line @JoakimDanielson

Comment: And what issue os that?